# docker, mongorestore - ERROR: root directory must be a dump of a single database

Tags: mongodb, docker

i had to update a collection on my local machine and want to upload this to a docker instance, here is my procedure

```
$ #backup local database
$ mongodump --collection styles --db ccc-mongo
$ tar -zcvf dump.tar.gz dump

$ scp dump.tar.gz me@remote:/home/me
$ ssh me@remote
me@remote: ~ $ docker exec -i mongo-dev sh -c "cd /tmp && tar xzf - && mongorestore --collection styles --db ccc-mongo" < dump.tar.gz
```

this gives me an error

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1
Fri Dec 18 16:05:26.768 ERROR: ERROR: root directory must be a dump of a single database
Fri Dec 18 16:05:26.768 ERROR:        when specifying a db name with --db
Import BSON files into MongoDB.
```

i just need to restore one collection without removing the other data, any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me

```
docker exec -i mongo-dev sh -c "cd /tmp && tar xzf - && mongorestore --db ccc-mongo --drop dump/ccc-mongo  && rm -Rf dump"  < dump.tar.gz
```

need to make sure in the dump to just include the collection i want to restore only

Answer (score 1):

**I figured out how to do it**

> **NOTE: please explain your question briefly. Question is not clear, please specify where you want to mondodump and restore your data - into server database or your ubuntu running computer. If into server from your local database then follow following steps:-**

Here are the instructions

Copy dump folder to server

```
scp -r /local_path/to/dump_folder root@111.222.33.4:/remote/path
```

SSH into server

```
ssh root@111.222.33.4
```

Copy from root of server to inside docker container

```
docker cp dump_folder mongodb:/dump_folder
```

Go into mongodb docker container

```
docker exec -it mongodb bash
```

check if copied folder exists
`ls` (you should see dump_folder, if you named it the same folder as in this example)

use mongorestore

```
mongorestore --drop -d AppName dump_folder
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20923195)

Comment: okay sure @NicolaBen I appreciate your suggestion. I will repost it again. Thanks.