# How to I fill a dockerized MongoDB with local data?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-volume

I'm trying to create a dockerized MongoDB with prefilled data. This is the command I use to run the container:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --network test-bridge --name test-mongo -v ~/db-backup:/data/db mongo
```

Unfortunately the data from ~/db-backup is not available inside the container. I tried using `mongorestore`, but I can't access the container that way.

What would be the correct way of creating a MongoDB docker container and filling it with data from the local machine?

Comment: What operating system is it? Which Docker version?

Comment: @jannis ubuntu 18.04, docker 18.09.04

Comment: [I solved it using this approach.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52439452/8604157)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this approach helps. Using docker-compose to set up your containers, you can create the mongodb one and do an import with another container that runs the import command like this:

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb_3.6
    hostname: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
         - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - labnet
    extra_hosts:
      - "locallab:127.0.0.1"

  mongo-import:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb_3.6_import
    hostname: mongo-import
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - labnet
    extra_hosts:
      - "locallab:127.0.0.1"
    volumes:
      - ./workspace:/tmp/workspace
    command: >
      bash -c " chmod +x /tmp/workspace/scripts/import.sh && /tmp/workspace/scripts/import.sh"
```

Having in your workspace/scripts folder the import.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /tmp/workspace/data/*.json; do
  echo "Inserting file " $file
  mongoimport --host mongo --db dbName --collection collectionName --type json --file $file --jsonArray
done
```

You can import an array of documents if you have them in array format inside a .json file.

The mongo-import container exists after doing his job.

Cheers